# Is it possible to give condition in MYSQL database column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am using MYSQL database for my application. Is it possible to give condition in each columns to accept values within the range.

For example, Lets say I am having column 'age' of integer type in a table. During insert statement this column should accept value only from 0-100.  i.e it should not accept negative values or greater than 100. If so, it should return me an error.

How could I setup this condition in MYSQL database?

Is there any alternative option to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's called a check constraint, but simply ignored by mysql :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL doesn't support CHECKs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html), you must do it in your application or use a Trigger or Stored Procedure to check for wrong data:

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

Comment: Does stored procedure supports checking all datatype column?
Because I need to check it for DATE type also